# Kinect-Projector-Mapping (calibration)

Tags: c++, opencv, unity-game-engine, kinect, camera-calibration

I am trying to track 3D printed objects with a kinect and project some texture/GUI onto them. The objects are lying on a table and the kinect and projector are hanging at the ceiling facing downwards.
The tracking part works great already and gives me a Position (x,y,z) and rotation (roll, pitch, yaw) of the object relative to the kinect.

Now I want to project some textures (or a solid color) onto these objects. My first idea was to remodel the scene in Unity by placing the objects mesh at the tracked position & rotation. Now I would place the unity camera at the projector's position and output the camera's image with the projector. For this to work I would need extrinsics of the projector (relative to the kinect) and intrinsics (f_x, f_y, c_x, c_y, distortion parameters) and apply them to the unity camera.

This is where I'm stuck. I tried running a camera calibration for my projector with OpenCV, but the results I'm getting are wrong. 
I create a chessboard pattern (6x5), store its inner corner positions as `vector<Point2f> projector2D` and display it via the projector. The kinects now sees the chessboard pattern and can detect its inner corners using `findChessboardCorners(...)` and store them in `vector<Point2f> kinect2D`. The kinects color and depth stream are calibrated and so I can get the real world 3D positions in meters relative from the kinect for each of these inner corners (`vector<Point3f> kinect3D = kinect->getXYZ(kinect2D)`).
I even hold up a big card board over the table in different poses, so the 3D positions aren't all in the same plane (2D projecteded chessboard stays the same).

From this 2D Projector <-> 3D real world mappings I should be able to compute the projectors intrinsics and extrinsics using opencv's `calibrateCamera(...)`. The extrinsics seem to make sense (kinect is roughly 1m above table and projector is roughly 1m above kinect) but the reprojection error is huge (> 100). What else can I do?

I even transformed the 3D points from the kinect's coordinate system to the table's coordinate system (so z=0), so that I don't have to use a guess for the camera's intrinsic parameters. The reprojection error is smaller now, but the intrinsics make no sense at all now (c_y should roughly be resolutionHeight / 2).

Here is my code:

```
bool FlowPut::calibrateProjector()
{
    // create fullscreen window on second screen
    namedWindow("projector", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    moveWindow("projector", -1920, 0);
    setWindowProperty("projector", CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

    // construct chessboard pattern image & store inner corner positions
    Size patternSize(6, 5);
    int width = 1920;
    int height = 1080;
    int marginX = 0.1f * width;
    int marginY = 0.1f * height;
    int widthPerCell = (width - 2*marginX) / (patternSize.width + 1);
    int heightPerCell = (height - 2*marginY) / (patternSize.height + 1);
    Mat chessBoardPattern(height, width, CV_8UC1, Scalar(255));

    vector<Point2f> cornersInProjector2D;
    for (int r = 0; r < patternSize.height + 1; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < patternSize.width + 1; ++c) {
            int x = marginX + c*widthPerCell;
            int y = marginY + r*heightPerCell;
            unsigned char color = 255 * ((c + r*(patternSize.width+1)) % 2);

            Rect roi(x, y, widthPerCell, heightPerCell);
            chessBoardPattern(roi).setTo(Scalar::all(color));

            if (r > 0 && c > 0)
                cornersInProjector2D.push_back(Point2f(x, y));
        }
    }

    imshow("projector", chessBoardPattern);
    waitKey(1);

    // acquire calibration pairs (projector 2d to kinect 3d) from multiple views
    int numViewsNeeded = 1;
    Mat colorFrame, colorFrameGray, depthFrame;
    vector<vector<Point3f> > objectPoints;
    vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints;
    vector<Eigen::Affine3f> transforms;

    while (objectPoints.size() < numViewsNeeded) {
        inputSource_->updateFrame();
        inputSource_->getColorFrameRegistered(colorFrame);
        inputSource_->getDepthFrame(depthFrame);
        imshow("color", colorFrame);
        imshow("depth", depthFrame);

        if (waitKey(1) == 112) { // "p"
            vector<Point2f> imagePointsLocal;
            vector<Point3f> objectPointsLocal;

            // find corners2D in kinect image
            vector<Point2f> cornersInKinect2D;
            cvtColor(colorFrame, colorFrameGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            if (!findChessboardCorners(colorFrameGray, patternSize, cornersInKinect2D, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS))
                continue;           
            cornerSubPix(colorFrameGray, cornersInKinect2D, Size(5, 5), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));


            // calculate 3d positions
            for (int i = 0; i < cornersInKinect2D.size(); ++i) {
                Point2f pProjector2D = cornersInProjector2D[i];
                Point2f pKinect2D = cornersInKinect2D[i];
                Point3f pKinect3D = inputSource_->getXYZ(pKinect2D.x, pKinect2D.y);

                if (isfinite(pKinect3D.x)) {
                    imagePointsLocal.push_back(pProjector2D);
                    objectPointsLocal.push_back(pKinect3D);
                }
            }

            // transform 3D positions to their own coordinate system
            PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new PointCloud<PointXYZ>());
            for (const Point3f &p : objectPointsLocal)
                cloud->push_back(PointXYZ(p.x, p.y, p.z));
            Eigen::Affine3f transform;
            PCLHelper::computePCATransform(cloud, transform, -Eigen::Vector3f::UnitZ());
            transformPointCloud(*cloud, *cloud, transform);
            for (int i = 0; i < imagePointsLocal.size(); ++i) {
                const PointXYZ &p = cloud->points[i];
                Point3f newP(p.x, p.y, p.z);
                cout << "projector2D: " << imagePointsLocal[i] << " kinect3D: " << objectPointsLocal[i] << " table3D: " << newP << endl;
                newP.z = 0;
                objectPointsLocal[i] = newP;
            }

            // display
            drawChessboardCorners(colorFrame, patternSize, Mat(cornersInKinect2D), true);
            imshow("calib_" + to_string(objectPoints.size()), colorFrame);

            // store
            objectPoints.push_back(objectPointsLocal);
            imagePoints.push_back(imagePointsLocal);
            transforms.push_back(transform);
        }
    }


    Mat cameraMatrix = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 0) = 1; // wild guess
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(1, 1) = 1; // wild guess
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 2) = 0.5 * width - 0.5;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(1, 2) = 0.5 * height - 0.5;
    cameraMatrix.at<double>(2, 2) = 1.0;

    Mat distCoeffs = Mat::zeros(8, 1, CV_64F);
    vector<Mat> rvecs, tvecs;

    int flags = 0;
    //flags = CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS;
    //flags |= CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO;
    //flags |= CV_CALIB_FIX_K1 | CV_CALIB_FIX_K2 | CV_CALIB_FIX_K3;
    //flags |= CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST;
    //flags |= CV_CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT;

    double projectionError = calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, Size(width, height), cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, flags);

    cout << "projectionError: " << projectionError << endl;

    cout << "cameraMatrix" << endl << cameraMatrix << endl;

    cout << "distCoeffs" << endl << distCoeffs << endl;

    cout << "translations" << endl;
    for (const Mat &tvec : tvecs)
        cout << tvec << endl;

    cout << "rotations" << endl;
    for (const Mat &rvec : rvecs) {
        Mat rMat;
        Rodrigues(rvec, rMat);
        cout << rMat << endl;
    }

    cout << "transforms" << endl;
    for (const Eigen::Affine3f aff : transforms)
        cout << aff.matrix() << endl;

    destroyWindow("projector");

    return true;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
projector2D: [411, 252] kinect3D: [0.395977, 0.127067, 0.949389] table3D: [0.341782, -0.172719, 0.00355369]
projector2D: [630, 252] kinect3D: [0.265477, 0.0954791, 0.964878] table3D: [0.206679, -0.173131, -0.00032872]
projector2D: [849, 252] kinect3D: [0.134238, 0.062928, 0.976424] table3D: [0.070973, -0.173593, -0.000131011]
projector2D: [1068, 252] kinect3D: [0.00167598, 0.0304205, 0.988115] table3D: [-0.0660144, -0.174406, -3.76701e-005]
projector2D: [1287, 252] kinect3D: [-0.132276, -0.0027268, 0.999953] table3D: [-0.204513, -0.17494, 9.65595e-005]
projector2D: [1506, 252] kinect3D: [-0.267018, -0.0363841, 1.01321] table3D: [-0.344021, -0.174915, -0.00101644]
projector2D: [411, 396] kinect3D: [0.416253, 0.0429084, 0.969855] table3D: [0.339156, -0.0838518, 0.000656247]
projector2D: [630, 396] kinect3D: [0.285356, 0.0111659, 0.981753] table3D: [0.203945, -0.0849229, 0.000327408]
projector2D: [849, 396] kinect3D: [0.154899, -0.0207928, 0.995246] table3D: [0.0689683, -0.0853642, -0.00152922]
projector2D: [1068, 396] kinect3D: [0.0232888, -0.052793, 1.0063] table3D: [-0.0669203, -0.0865392, -0.000952244]
projector2D: [1287, 396] kinect3D: [-0.107317, -0.0865693, 1.01591] table3D: [-0.202145, -0.0860579, 0.00137049]
projector2D: [1506, 396] kinect3D: [-0.240572, -0.120209, 1.02912] table3D: [-0.340208, -0.0856784, 0.000245035]
projector2D: [411, 540] kinect3D: [0.436322, -0.0395136, 0.989427] table3D: [0.33683, 0.0031431, -0.00172836]
projector2D: [630, 540] kinect3D: [0.306071, -0.0707654, 0.99843] table3D: [0.202615, 0.00120574, 0.000643492]
projector2D: [849, 540] kinect3D: [0.17609, -0.102898, 1.01177] table3D: [0.0680687, 0.00102064, -0.00104523]
projector2D: [1068, 540] kinect3D: [0.0463136, -0.136332, 1.02396] table3D: [-0.0664956, 0.00189427, -0.00133801]
projector2D: [1287, 540] kinect3D: [-0.0848548, -0.16929, 1.03384] table3D: [-0.202087, 0.00150889, 0.00057447]
projector2D: [1506, 540] kinect3D: [-0.216815, -0.202081, 1.04565] table3D: [-0.338572, 0.00114283, 0.000584126]
projector2D: [411, 684] kinect3D: [0.454245, -0.120754, 1.00522] table3D: [0.333046, 0.0877317, -0.00059998]
projector2D: [630, 684] kinect3D: [0.326484, -0.152412, 1.01794] table3D: [0.200814, 0.0875426, -0.00185949]
projector2D: [849, 684] kinect3D: [0.196626, -0.183715, 1.02961] table3D: [0.0667335, 0.0862762, -0.00209552]
projector2D: [1068, 684] kinect3D: [0.0686593, -0.217207, 1.04014] table3D: [-0.0659516, 0.0873433, -0.000820816]
projector2D: [1287, 684] kinect3D: [-0.0621101, -0.249929, 1.05224] table3D: [-0.201294, 0.0872703, -0.00113678]
projector2D: [1506, 684] kinect3D: [-0.191983, -0.282971, 1.06092] table3D: [-0.335551, 0.0870624, 0.00190979]
projector2D: [411, 828] kinect3D: [0.471262, -0.199975, 1.01816] table3D: [0.329126, 0.169617, 0.00292253]
projector2D: [630, 828] kinect3D: [0.344672, -0.231911, 1.0313] table3D: [0.197922, 0.170072, 0.00127441]
projector2D: [849, 828] kinect3D: [0.217777, -0.263573, 1.04313] table3D: [0.0666032, 0.169934, 0.000858486]
projector2D: [1068, 828] kinect3D: [0.0893882, -0.296656, 1.05822] table3D: [-0.0667883, 0.171399, -0.0023976]
projector2D: [1287, 828] kinect3D: [-0.0399663, -0.329776, 1.06995] table3D: [-0.200828, 0.171994, -0.00232649]
projector2D: [1506, 828] kinect3D: [-0.167329, -0.361072, 1.07448] table3D: [-0.331874, 0.169959, 0.00432938]
projectionError: 1.19223
cameraMatrix
[2019.16764855345, 0, 948.0981380429103;
 0, 2074.876304934358, 370.5848700207086;
 0, 0, 1]
distCoeffs
[0.1297589355520183;
 -3.511519048733476;
 -0.005197028270677967;
 -0.012067317877384;
 23.18698415487345]
translations
[0.00771433482275145;
 0.1003592362542408;
 1.242695870159661]
rotations
[-0.9999443491624133, -0.003817450239401587, -0.009834920021401414;
 -0.002546646669596347, 0.9920108573608824, -0.1261268150270501;
 0.01023783028272609, -0.1260947498978334, -0.9919653728227135]
transforms
  0.966158   0.242777 -0.0871718  0.0111167
   0.25557  -0.946741   0.195871  -0.339577
-0.0349761  -0.211521  -0.976747   0.971594
         0          0          0          1
```

Even if I would have a correct calibration for my projector, how would I set these values in Unity or is there an even better solution without Unity?
Any help is highly appreciated!